# Mutable class attributes with different importing strategies

Tags: python, python-3.6

I've recently stumbled upon a weird behavior of the mutable class attributes.
Theoretically (and practically), a mutable argument defined on a class level will be shared within all instances until any instance will overwrite the reference.

In our project, we have directory structure similar to below:

```
├─── main.py
└─── src
    ├─── __init__.py
    ├─── cache_user.py
    └─── common_cache.py
```

#### common_cache.py:

```
class CommonCache:
    cache = {}
```

#### cache_user.py:

```
from .common_cache import CommonCache


class CacheUser(CommonCache):
    pass
```

#### main.py:

```
from src.cache_user import CacheUser
from src.common_cache import CommonCache

common_cache = CommonCache()
cache_user = CacheUser()
print(id(common_cache.cache))
print(id(CommonCache.cache))
print(id(cache_user.cache))
print(id(CacheUser.cache))
```

#### Result of running main.py:

```
2163305605304
2163305605304
2163305605304
2163305605304
```

All ID's are the same as expected which proves, that all instances and classes are sharing common reference to the same dictionary. However, when we add `src` directory into `PYTHONPATH` and slightly change imports, something weird will happen.

#### cache_user.py:

```
from src.common_cache import CommonCache


class CacheUser(CommonCache):
    pass
```

#### main.py

```
from cache_user import CacheUser
from common_cache import CommonCache

common_cache = CommonCache()
cache_user = CacheUser()
print(id(common_cache.cache))
print(id(CommonCache.cache))
print(id(cache_user.cache))
print(id(CacheUser.cache))
```

#### Result of running main.py:

```
2067930459016
2067930459016
2067930458440
2067930458440
```

Now, `CommonCache` (and instances) have their own `cache` dictionary, different from `CacheUser` (and instances). What happened? The only thing that changes is the method how we do imports. If we will put breakpoint in `CommonCache` class we can clearly see, that `cache = {}` is executed twice - once per import. If we would have more than one class that does import of `CommonCache`, only the distinct import methods will trigger `cache = {}`.

Solving this issue in our project wasn't just unifying import method since the project is too big to do that. Our solution is to create `CacheStorage` class that is imported only by `CommonCache`, and the real `cache` dict is stored within `CacheStorage`.

So, why is it happening? I can't find any explanation for this situation.
Also, how to deal with that? Is there any better solution than creating a `CacheStorage` object?

This was tested in Python3.6 on CentOS and Windows.

Comment: I think `src.common_cache` and `common_cache` are recognized as different modules though they point to the same file. To archive the singleton pattern of class variable / module variable, the name how a module get imported should be standardized among the related files.

Comment: Yes, it is quite clear from the example. But the main question is why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

This suggests that modules are identified by their "import" name rather than the absolute file of the module file. In your case, a module `src.common_cache` is found in `.` while another module `common_cache` in `./src`.

[When a new module is imported, each statement get executed](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html). Therefore, there are two distinct modules imported (what the Python interpreter think):

- one `CommonCache` defined in the module `src.common_cache`
- one `CommonCache` defined in the module `common_cache`.

This assertion also show both `CommonCache` are not refered to the same class.

```
assert src.common_cache.CommonCache is not common_cache.CommonCache
```

Comment: That's clear. But can you tell why it does work this way if the file path is the same in both cases? Is it a bug or a feature? If feature, what are the use cases?

Comment: This is not a bug nor feature. This is how the import system work. Python first search the required in the memory to see if it is loaded. If not, Python search it in `sys.path` (related to `PYTHONPATH`)  one by one or raise `ImportError`.

Comment: Ok, but why `src.common_cache` and `common_cache` are treated as a different modules if their target is the same file? You can see that in `sys.modules`. That seems like a bug. Note that in first example the import statement is executed only once. The `ImportError` is never raised, it just imports the same file twice if it is within `PYTHONPATH`. If the key in `sys.modules` would be full file path instead of relative path, both modules will be treated as one.